# Searching a character position in a string in a cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a string in a cell and want to search for position of a character occurring multiple times at different positions and put the posing in other cell.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would see these results taking shape so I took the liberty to come up with the following using Microsoft365:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)=B2))
```

Or, formula in `C3`:

```
=FILTER(SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)=B3)
```